# apt unmet dependencies, but the package is there

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, deb

I've made a `deb` package with `debuild` on Ubuntu a while back, now I want to use it on a new system. Three packages, actually: a library with an app and a configuration file installed as a package. First, I install the library:

```
sms@sms-ubu:/Github/mentorsms$ sudo apt install ./mentorsmslib_1.0_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mentorsmslib' instead of './mentorsmslib_1.0_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mentorsmslib
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/54.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 176 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /Github/mentorsms/mentorsmslib_1.0_amd64.deb mentorsmslib amd64 1.0 [54.6 kB]
Selecting previously unselected package mentorsmslib.
(Reading database ... 207633 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mentorsmslib_1.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mentorsmslib (1.0) ...
Setting up mentorsmslib (1.0) ...
```

Then the configuration file:

```
sms@sms-ubu:/Github/smartfloorcontrol$ sudo apt install ./smartfloorcontrol-hdmi_1.0_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'smartfloorcontrol-hdmi' instead of './smartfloorcontrol-hdmi_1.0_amd64.deb'
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  smartfloorcontrol-hdmi
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,310 B of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /Github/smartfloorcontrol/smartfloorcontrol-hdmi_1.0_amd64.deb smartfloorcontrol-hdmi amd64 1.0 [1,310 B]
Selecting previously unselected package smartfloorcontrol-hdmi.
(Reading database ... 207692 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../smartfloorcontrol-hdmi_1.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking smartfloorcontrol-hdmi (1.0) ...
Setting up smartfloorcontrol-hdmi (1.0) ...
```

And finally the app, and the error shows up here:

```
sms@sms-ubu:/Github/smartfloorcontrol$ sudo apt install ./smartfloorcontrol_1.0_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'smartfloorcontrol' instead of './smartfloorcontrol_1.0_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 smartfloorcontrol : Depends: smartfloorcontrol-config (= 1.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As you can see, it doesn't see smartfloorcontrol-config package, but it's there (provided by smartfloorcontrol-hdmi):

```
sms@sms-ubu:/Github/smartfloorcontrol$ dpkg -s smartfloorcontrol-hdmi
Package: smartfloorcontrol-hdmi
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 12
Maintainer: Szymon M. Sabat <capt_sms@protonmail.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: smartfloorcontrol
Version: 1.0
Provides: smartfloorcontrol-config
Conffiles:
 /etc/smartfloorcontrol/smartfloorcontrolProj.ini 67bb651a629ef90e8a6d52f393f0bcd5
Description: SmartFloor Control configuration
 Configures smartfloorcontrol to work with HDMI projectors.
```

I am positive it worked 3 months ago on different Ubuntu 22.04 PC. Did I forgot something I did before?